# How to increase file size to go unnoticed in windows defender?

Tags: linux, dd, windows-defender

The maximum file size that windows defender can scan is 2G, so I ran this command on a Linux machine to increase the file's size. Then I copied it over to my windows machine.

dd if=/dev/zero bs=1G seek=3 count=0 of=malware.exe

I tried then running it on my windows machine, but windows defender still interrupted its execution. I think the problem could be because the "blank" bytes were added to the end of the file, so windows defender noticed what was going on. Is there a way to increase the file size and have the file still go undetected?

If I am not being clear, and did something wrong, please be kind. :)

Comment: Why are you trying to evade Windows Defender?

Comment: I'm practicing ethical hacking. If I was really trying to actually illegally hack something would I post it online for everyone to see? Sorry if that sounded harsh. I'm trying to replicate something I saw in a video.

Comment: @squillman: Testing the limits opens the chance for improvement in knowledge. So doing such things is not a bad or evil idea.

Comment: @CarsonOuckama Not trying to be harsh.  We get plenty here where ethics are questionable.

Comment: @dodrg I agree with the improvement in knowledge, but there's plenty of times where the answer provides something for ill-intent

Comment: you say that Defender "interrupted execution", but previously you referred to scanning. file scanning execution analysis function quite differently, and  in the case of the later, its unlikely that the whole file needs be read to perform heuristic and behavioral analysis. you also may be running afoul of reputational analysis, like SmartScan, where executables are checked online with MS to determine if they are "known". while "at rest" scans will skip the file due to its size, that should not impact defenders ability to detect the execution of a malicious application.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that Windows Defender has a 2GB file limit seems to be incorrect.  It doesnt make any sense to have a limit, as bad actors would try to do what you are doing.

The link below allows you to SET a maximum size, with the default being "No limit."  This definitely implies that the limit is what the maximum size of a file on the filesystem being read.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/configure-advanced-scan-types-microsoft-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide

Other links I have found offer similar information.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Windows Defender is a 32bit process, also on 64bit Windows.
The easy hint: It is stored with the Programms using the `x86`:
`%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Windows Defender\`

As a 32 bit process it can't exceed 2 GB.

Details about this limit you can find here:
SuperUser: [Why do 32-bit processes have a 2 GB RAM limit?](https://superuser.com/questions/1163749/why-do-32-bit-processes-have-a-2-gb-ram-limit)